# Facebook saves my 404 Open Graph data (I use Varnish to cache)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, facebook-opengraph, varnish

I will try to explain this to see if anyone could have a clue. We cant figure out the problem since months and it is driving me crazy.

We have a site with a custom CMS developed. We use Varnish to cache articles. If you're not logged in, you should see the cached article by Varnish. If you're logged in, you should see the live article.

We have a feature to program the publishing of the article. So, maybe we write an article, and set to publish tomorrow at 9am. When is published, a cached version of the article is created by Varnish.

The problem is that after the article is published, Facebook (we dont understand why) is saving the 404 Open Graph data. It is like Facebook cant reach the cached article, or maybe is trying to access it before the cached version is created (maybe beacuse we added the Facebook Comments plugin and it is calling Facebook to retrieve the comments of the URL that is not still cached?)

I'm not sure if the problem is clear, but we are really lost and can't fix it. All the scheduling script is uselss if once the article is published, no one can share it on Facebook because it has the wrong Open Graph data (from the 404)

Comment: If the Comments plugin is to blame – well then you should not embed that before the article is published.

Comment: I thought that was the case, so now we only show it if the article is published. But the problem is still there. I think maybe is something calling facebook just when the article is published but the Varnish cache is not just ready yet. Although it seems strange that something like that could happen...